# How to use ember-power-select with Ember-Data results

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

G'day,

I was trying to load model data from a store.findAll() call into the ember-power-select component. The data from findAll() loads into the component fine, but I needed to set the initial selected item, and nothing I did seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution will ask server twice. Check this solution (es6 syntax)

```
setupController(controller, model) {
  controller.set('model', model);
  this.store.findAll('club').then(clubs => {
    controller.set('clubs', clubs);
    // i am not sure if the function is called filter, but it should be close enough
    return clubs.filter(club => clubs.get('id') === model.get('clubId')).get('firstObject');
  }).then(selectedClub =>  controller.set('selectedClub', selectedClub)).catch(err => {
    console.log("Error:", err);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I had figured that it would query against the cache without the second dip, but checking the server you're right, it's doing two fetches... will give this a crack tonight.

Answer (score 0):

The trick was to use the get() method with 'firstObject' after you pull the element out of the DS cache with store.query.

Here's what I wound up doing - if anyone has a more elegant way of doing this I'd love to hear...

```
setupController: function(controller, model) {
  var _this = this;

  controller.set('model',model);

  _this.store.findAll('club')
  .then(function(results){
     controller.set('clubs', results);
     return _this.store.query('club', {id:model.get('clubId')});
  })
  .then(function(result){
     controller.set('selectedClub', result.get('firstObject'));
  })
  .catch(function(err){
    console.log("Error:",err);
  });
```

},